# is there a way to let braces in simple single-line statements appear on one line in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting

I have numerous statments like:

```
if (DEBUG) { system.out.println(something); }
```

or getter/setter like

```
public void setSomething(String something) { this.something = something; }
```

and I want them to appear like this.
Is there a way to achieve this? The formatter always breaks the lines and I fear that I can't tell him to format them to a single line, but is there a possibility to tell him to not break the lines (for getter/setter at least)?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter and select "Edit..."

A dialog pops up that lets you modify tons of stuff for the formatter. What you need is in the tabs "Control Statements" and "Line Wrapping". You can at least get the compact if sentences, but not sure exactly what to set to get the compact methods.

Comment: 'Compact' applies to if-statements without braces, that is not an option since I don't neglect them.